# code igniter-How to have login and register in same page using TankAuth method

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I need to have login and register in same view

here is my controller

```
       function login()
{
     // do something

        $this->load->view('auth/login_form', $data);
    }
}


       function register()
{

                // do something

        $this->load->view('auth/login_form', $data);
    }
}
```

here is my view 
login form

```
   <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>

   //login form
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

signup form

```
            <?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>

   //sign up form
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

on submit both form loads , how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

U need to set different methods for submit forms.

Example:

```
<?= form_open('controller/method_login'); ?>
   //login form html code
  <?= form_close(); ?>

   <?= form_open('controller/method_register'); ?>
   //sign up form html code
  <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Then create methods method_login and method_register inside you controller where u can receive POST data and manipulate further to do validate and login/register user based on method.

Hope I helped you out.

Comment: i have did the same submitting forms to different controller function but still same issue <?php  form_open('controller/login'); ?> <?php  form_open('controller/register'); ?>

Comment: @vellaidurai Try to add in form_open second parameter ['method' => 'GET'] and comment here what u get if URL when submit login form and when submit register form.

Comment: or array('method' => 'get') if you using php version less than 5.6

Answer (score 0):

1) add a hidden field to identify the operation

ex: < input type="hidden" name="op" value="login" />

Likewise add a filed as registration for other form.

Now in controller based on the op field u can perform the operation.

Comment: Please check now... Hidden fields can be used.